# Rails: 'Email has already been taken' for every email I enter

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**Update:** 
Checking the console, a lot of the users are actually going into the database, even when this error message appears!

Even weirder, you will notice that I have a redirect to root_path on a successful save to the database. it never goes there. This is the log. If it saves, it sometimes goes to the show action but there's actually a moment when the browser appears to get stuck, everything blanks it and I have to click in the address field to push it through to show.index.html.

```
Redirected to http://localhost:3000root_path
Completed 302 Found in 34ms
[2012-01-08 18:08:27] ERROR URI::InvalidURIError: the scheme http does not accept registry part: localhost:3000root_path (or bad hostname?)
    /Users/mel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/generic.rb:746:in `rescue in merge'
    /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/generic.rb:743:in `merge'
    /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpresponse.rb:163:in `setup_header'
    /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpresponse.rb:101:in `send_response'
    /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:86:in `run'
    /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:183:in `block in start_thread'
```

**Original Question:**

I'm creating a form for users to sign up to win an ipad. It's got two fields, email and name. 
When I submit the form, I keep getting the same error message no matter what email i enter

```
1 error prohibited this from being saved:

There were problems with the following fields:

    Email has already been taken
```

Strangely, when I debug params, it shows whatever new email address I enter.

```
utf8: "\xE2\x9C\x93"
authenticity_token: UgkHFLBfKYM2tZ11u6ItWvPS5XeTIMhFuJDwvhgqe30=
ipad: !map:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess 
  name: Amy
  email: franz@gmail.com
commit: Sign up
action: create
controller: ipads
```

Anyone have any idea? I'm a bit of a noob...

I'm just adding this code to an Enki blog I'm making on Rails...

I have this validation on my ipad.rb model  (note, I had a column for a Twitter address in the migration that I'm just ignoring in the form)

```
attr_accessible :name, :email, :twitter

validates :name, :presence => true,
         :length   => { :maximum => 50 }
validates :email, :presence => true,
                  :uniqueness => true
```

This is my ipads_controller.rb

```
class IpadsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @ipad = Ipad.new
    @title = "iPad Contest"
  end

  def create
    @ipad = Ipad.new(params[:ipad])
    if @ipad.save
      redirect_to 'root_path'
    else
      @title = "Poo"
      render 'new'
    end
  end


end
```

This is my new.html.erb

```
<h1>Win an iPad</h1>
<%= @title %>

<h1>Sign up for iPad</h1>

<%= form_for(@ipad) do |f| %>
<%= render 'shared/errror_messages' %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Sign up" %>
  </div>
<% end %>


<%= debug params %>
```

Comment: Have you included `:email` in `attr_accessible` in your model?

Comment: Yes, I did. I'll update the OP. attr_accessible :name, :email, :twitter

Comment: The error message is actually on the User model, not the iPad model

`1 error prohibited this **user** from being saved:`

Would you update how the user model relates to the iPad model?

Comment: @JesseWolgamott thanks, that's because I copied the code from somewhere else, forgot to change that part, although I did change all the other variables associated with the error message.

Comment: change redirect_to 'root_path' to `redirect_to root_path` and see if you still have problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using redirect_to root_path instead of redirect_to 'root_path' fixed it. Noob error.